# C - reading from stdin with a file?

Tags: c, file, shell, stdin, getchar

So I have a text file that I'm using in the same directory as my C program and I'm using MinGW as the compiler. This is my input:

```
./program "hello" > helloworld.txt
```

In my program in the main function, I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char c;
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
printf("test\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Nothing is printing. The text file definitely has lines in it. I don't know what's going on. This assignment voids the use of fopen() and all that. It is getchar() and stdin only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command isn't reading from the text file, it's writing to it.  If you want to read from it, you need to do this:

```
./program < helloworld.txt
```

helloworld.txt:

```
this
is a
test
```

Output:

```
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistype. The correct input has the '<'. Sorry about that :/

Comment: @Laefica If you're using `<` it should be working.  See my edit.

Comment: Yep, it works. I'm stupid. Glad this question will serve as reference to those who confuse < with > in the future though xD